# Getting error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'"

Tags: python, flask

```
for key in usersDict:
    user = usersDict.get(key)
    usersList.append(user)
    if user.get_Quantity() == 0:
        emptyStock = user.get_Name()
        flash("%s is out of stock!!")%emptyStock
    else:
        continue
```

Error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Is it wrong to use `%s` for a string?

Comment: flash("%s is out of stock!!",emptyStock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis is in the wrong place.

> flash("%s is out of stock!!")%emptyStock

should be

```
flash("%s is out of stock!!"%emptyStock)
```